# django e postgres"DETAIL: Key (field)=() is duplicated"

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i been makein migrations in my database, and i received this error:

(env)$ python manage.py migrate
System check identified some issues:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, models, sessions, sites, socialaccount
Running migrations:
  Applying models.0018_auto_20210809_1124...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: could not create unique index "models_funcionario_cpf_funcionario_d9311e70_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (cpf_funcionario)=() is duplicated.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 244, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 594, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 196, in _alter_field
    super()._alter_field(
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 786, in _alter_field
    self.execute(self._create_unique_sql(model, [new_field.column]))
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/lucas/MaxiLimpService/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "models_funcionario_cpf_funcionario_d9311e70_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (cpf_funcionario)=() is duplicated.
```

my migrations

(env) lucas@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:~/MaxiLimpService$ python manage.py showmigrations

```
System check identified some issues:

        
account
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_email_max_length
 [X] 0003_auto_20210712_1617
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
cadastro
 (no migrations)
consulta
 (no migrations)
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
editar
 (no migrations)
localDeTrabalho
 (no migrations)
models
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20210706_1002
 [X] 0003_auto_20210708_0922
 [X] 0004_alter_funcionario_id_unidade
 [X] 0005_horarioservico_unidade
 [X] 0006_alter_horarioservico_unidade
 [X] 0007_alter_horarioservico_data_horario_servico
 [X] 0008_auto_20210727_1737
 [X] 0009_alter_horarioservico_data_horario_servico
 [X] 0010_chamadoassistencia
 [X] 0011_alter_chamadoassistencia_id_funcionario
 [X] 0012_alter_chamadoassistencia_titulo
 [X] 0013_alter_folgafuncionario_motivo_folga
 [X] 0014_alter_horarioservico_data_horario_servico
 [X] 0015_alter_horarioservico_data_horario_servico
 [X] 0016_alter_horarioservico_data_horario_servico
 [X] 0017_alter_horarioservico_unidade
 [ ] 0018_auto_20210809_1124
paginaInicial
 (no migrations)
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
sites
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_domain_unique
socialaccount
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_token_max_lengths
 [X] 0003_extra_data_default_dict
 [X] 0004_auto_20210712_1617
```

my model funcionario:

```
class Funcionario(AbstractUser):
    rg_funcionario = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cpf_funcionario = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length=200)

    id_funcao_funcionario = models.ForeignKey(FuncaoFuncionario, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    telefone_funcionario = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    id_unidade = models.ForeignKey(Unidade, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    rua = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cep = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.first_name) + " " + str(self.last_name) + " (" + str(self.cpf_funcionario) + ")"
```

I did a migration and when I went makemigration it happened

Comment: What could be happen is a duplicate value in Database. Even with empty values in cpf_funcionario.
Try clean this values of Funcionario or even insert new values on Funcionario.cpf_funcionario.

Comment: this worked, thanks, so easy lol